# Where to buy third-party equipment?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm new on Diablo III, I've buy this game after **Auction House** official closure, so it's harder for me to build my own (decent) equipment.

I've **11 millions** and I know that is not much money, but anyways I can't know the prices of nothing 'cause there is no an **Auction House** to compare prices and I've never buy from anyone.

Before do nothing I've investigated about the ways to buy or trade efficientlly in Diablo III, and I've seen a **LOT** of Scammers videos in Youtube, and posts of people in the official **Blizzard** forum and **Diablo3Fans** forum about backdoors/bugs/hacks in the trade system with people that stole ALL your money in less than 2 seconds... so I'm very scared to loose my money.

There is a safe (and possible fast) way to buy equipment from other people in this game? I mean how to get attention to buy/sell and how to do it safelly? 'cause if I need to send an mp for each player to know what items he have and if he want trade or sell then it can takes forever.

Comment: You can't even trade gold anymore, and legendaries are bound to your account.  Trading is basically dead.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the info, that means I only can trade normal and magic equipment, and other 'normal' items? then there is any way to buy from others?

Comment: There is no way to buy anything of value - not legendaries, not recipes, not higher-level gems. To gear up your character, you should join one of efficient farming groups and farm with them - either doing split bounties, or rifting. It won't take long to improve your character with Loot 2.0.

Comment: You could just, well, play the game... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as how with Loot 2.0 players can no longer trade gold, and legendary items are account bound (unless they drop for someone you are in a party with at the time), there isn't really any way for you to buy any gear from others. You can trade rare, magic, and normal items with other players, but not for gold. Health potions can be traded.

Comment: thankyou for your answer but one thing is incorrect, I've seen people dropping legendary items (just for trolling newbies like me) and their legendary items can't be taken from ground, seems a very secure system, I've just would like to clarify that. thanks again

Comment: The only way they could drop those legendaries is if those two players were in the same party when it dropped for one of them, or, if the legendary item is a fairly old one (before the patch basically) and therefore not account bound.

Comment: @ElektroStudios He didn't say Legendaries can't be dropped. He said they can not be traded. **Bunyip**, any legendary items can be *dropped no the ground*. Uneligible players can't pick them up, but Mother Earth accepts them.

Comment: @Orc JMR My English is not very good, I understood that Bunyvip said that if a player drops himself a legendary item to ground another player can pick it, I've just clarified that was incorrect, sorry if I've understood bad. thanks

Comment: @ElektroStudios He meant items drop from a monster *for* someone else.